# Is there any software for using mobile device as an air mouse for Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse, software-recommendation, application-development

I just want to know if there is any software available as an air mouse(by air mouse I mean which you hover in air to move the cursor using the IR blaster in the phone). Is there is any development going on over it? 
I found a software that worked on Windows, I just wanted to know if there's something like that in Ubuntu.